# How to create a Rule to email referenced authors after saving new content?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules, emails

I am trying to create a review platform. I have multiple content types, and I have created ***review*** content types which are referenced to these content types.

I want to create an action (tell me if you think there is a better way) which would send an email to the original content author to notify them that a review has been published about their content.

Any ideas how to do this or if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I think that with the answer you posted yourself (which works for you), you've been lucky quite a bit. Especially because of the "`:0`" part in the token you used: that sounds like your reference field is a multi value field (which you didn't say in your question). So therefor your answer will only work for the 1st referenced node, ie if you have multiple referenced nodes, any additional authors (of the other nodes) will never receive such eMail. As per your "***tell me if you think there is a better way***": read on for some more details to make that also work ...

Create a rule like so (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format):

```
{ "rules_send_email_to_selected_authors" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send eMail to selected authors",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : {
      "node_insert--review" : { "bundle" : "review" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:referenced-field" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "current_referenced_node" : "Current referenced node" },
          "DO" : [
            { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "An eMail about this new content with title \u0022[node:title]\u0022 and URL [node:url] will be delivered to [current-referenced-node:author:mail]." } },
            { "mail" : {
                "to" : "[current-referenced-node:author:mail]",
                "subject" : "You have new mail ...",
                "message" : "New content was created with title [node:title] ... You can read about it at [node:url].",
                "language" : [ "" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about the above rule:

- **Rules Event**: After saving new content of type "Review" (adapt the type to fit your needs).
- **Rules Action**: a "loop" for all selected values of a multi value select list (contains the referenced content types). For each item (= `current_referenced_node`), an eMail is created with some subject and message that also contains the title and url of the node being created. Note: this will send 1 separated eMail to each of the selected eMail IDs.

If you have the Rules UI enabled, you can import the above rule in your own site, after you adapt the machine names of the content type and the field name containing the list of referenced content types.

After you're convinced the rule works as expected, you may want to remove the Rules Action that displays a message after the node is saved (with `drupal_message`).

**Video tutorial**: have a look at the [List and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops) video which show a similar scenario.

Comment: Hi Pierre,  I am sure that this works, and I hope that it will be of use to me and others in the future.  I am quite happy with the solution I have right now though.  Thanks again for the great comments and putting in the time and effort to write this post.

Comment: @marknewton merci for the feedback, and accept!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's a LOT easier than I thought. I found that the following worked for me so far:

```
node:referenced-field:0:author:mail
```

I hope that this helps someone.